# PHP - Formated Date to UNIX to iCal

Tags: php, date, icalendar, strtotime

I'm trying to format my stored dates `2013-04-23 19:00` to iCal format: `20130423T190000`.
Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
$start = strtotime($event["event_start"]);
$start = date('Ymd\THis',$start);
```

This code returns `19691231T190000`.

I thought that because the starting string is missing seconds, that could have been the problem, but after trying `$start = strtotime($event["event_start"] . ":00");` I've ruled that out.

Comment: doesn't matter if event_start is "missing" seconds. strtotime returns a unix timestamp, which is seconds since midnight Jan 1/1970. you'll get seconds out of any formatted date you produce from that timestamp, even if they end up being `:00` all the time anyways.

Comment: So you're saying that with or without seconds, `strtotime()` returns the same.

Comment: as long as what you feed into strtotime is a format it can understand, you'll get a "seconds" value out of it. that value always has implicit seconds, because it's stated **IN** seconds. formatting it to an h:m:s format will just make :s come out as zeroes. e.g. strtotime('7pm') would never devolve to (say) 7:00:01, because that :01 wasn't in the time value to begin with.

Comment: Understood, thanks. So is `2013-04-23 19:00` a format that `strtotime()` can understand?

Comment: yep, it is. you can test it trivially yourself: `echo date('r', strtotime('2013-04-23 19:00'))`. if the output's close to what you put in (minus formatting and maybe timezone differences), it works.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, but this information doesn't help me proceed. It only suggests that my second line `$start = date('Ymd\THis',$start);` is invalid. Which I don't think is the case.

Comment: yeah, it does mean event_start isn't being parsed properly. strtotime is returning a boolean false to indicate failure, which PHP then typecasts to int 0 when you pass it to date(). timestamp 0 is midnight Jan 1/1970 UTC, so your system is in UTC+5, hence Dec 31/1969.

Comment: Yes, start_date was blank (invalid). Case closed ;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cYou appear to be missing something.
Are you sure $event["event_start"] is populated.

```
date('Ymd\THis',strtotime('2013-04-23 19:00')) == 20130423T190000
```

**While**

```
date('Ymd\THis',strtotime('')) == 19691231T190000
```

Check value of $event["event_start"].

**EDIT:**
Hint was that 1969 is suspiciously close to UNIX epoch of 1970.

FROM marc b -> the difference was the timezone of UTC +5

Comment: I like this idea... I'll check this out.

Comment: Comment on your edit: Yes, Marc B explains why it was outputing `19691231T190000` (because of my timezone being UTC+5).

Comment: EDITED to reflect all info

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = "DTSTART;TZID=<your timezone>:".date('Ymd', strtotime($start));
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php